# HTTP 2 Protocol using WebClient

Tags: .net, http

New HTTP 2 Protocol will allow multiple file sent using single request, and it keeps the request open. If like that, a WebClient need to have callback each time a file is received,

1. Is there any .NET library that do that on HTTP 2?
2. Or is there any sample using existing WebClient?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP 2 is not yet adopted by .NET Framework. It might require serious API changes, so you need to wait.

If you are willing to contribute you can go to https://github.com/dotnet/corefx.